How do I find a replacement fan motor that fits?
I have a bathroom fan mounting bracket installed in the 70's that I do not have a fan motor for. I am trying to find a replacement or figure out how to replace the whole bracket. I've tried searching online but most kits seem based on dimensions or model numbers of the previous fan. I don't know the model number of the old fan and I can't seem to find a kit for these dimensions (9" x 7 1/2"):

I also cannot find a way to remove the bracket entirely, I think I would have to remove part of the ceiling in order to do that. I would prefer replacing the motor and grille but can't seem to find one that fits.
Do you know what fan motor might fit this bracket?

I would email than picture to Broan and ask them.

Look online, for example https://www.amazon.com/Broan-C350BN-Replacement-Motor-Wheel/dp/B0028UC8KU/ref=sr_1_52, that might be a near fit. You might need tin-snips or a nibbling tool and a drill to adapt it to fit inside the old mount, and it might not fit,  but at ~US$22, one might take a chance. Many more can be seen at https://www.amazon.com/s?k=bathroom+vent+fan+motor,  but I wouldn't spend much on a fan mount I'd likely have to cut up.

Too bad the painter was a lazy MFer and sprayed the entire fan, or you could pull a part number...

Emailing Broan technical support produced a result. It appears this is a Mercury by Nutone style bath fan. Unfortunately they do not offer replacement parts for this model.



